# What is this error code?

Tags: solidity, nft, hardhat, goerli

I am running code to mint an NFT, after the contract deploys, I am getting this error message but I dont really know what to take from it. Is there something specific that could tell me the reason I am getting this error message?

Command I am running:

```
npx hardhat run scripts/deploy.js --network goerli
```

Here is my deploy code:

```
const deployContract = async () => {
    const nftContractFactory = await hre.ethers.getContractFactory('JSNFT');
    const nftContract = await nftContractFactory.deploy({gasPrice: 8000000000});
    await nftContract.deployed();
    console.log("Contract deployed to:", nftContract.address);
    const aiImages = [
      '{ "name": "JS-NFT-AI-ART-2", "description": "AI art created by JS-NFT", "image": "https://www.dropbox.com/s/o5h5f9deg7nm5cj/AI-POST-WORLD-2.jpeg?raw=1" }',
      '{ "name": "JS-NFT-AI-ART", "description": "AI art created by JS-NFT", "image": "https://www.dropbox.com/s/toq98op6t8g9wts/AI-POST-WORD-1.jpeg?raw=1" }'
    ] 

    let itemID = 0
    while(itemID <= aiImages.length - 1) {
      await nftContract.setNFTData(itemID, aiImages[itemID])
      let txn = await nftContract.makeJSNFT()
      await txn.wait()
      await nftContract.tokenURI(itemID)
      itemID++;
    }
  };


const main = async () => {
    try {
      await deployContract();
      process.exit(0);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      process.exit(1);
    }
  };
  
  main();
```

Error Message:

```
Contract deployed to: 0x2e95DE6abF74a45185c3541Ca1204c6f59B3ee13
Error: transaction failed [ See: https://links.ethers.org/v5-errors-CALL_EXCEPTION ] (transactionHash="0x63dfd6f931550ebffd459049ce04b68e759a8d2dcedf62e2eaa671deb30c998b", transaction={"hash":"0x63dfd6f931550ebffd459049ce04b68e759a8d2dcedf62e2eaa671deb30c998b","type":0,"accessList":null,"blockHash":null,"blockNumber":null,"transactionIndex":null,"confirmations":0,"from":"0x88e6Bc4Fcb2665b2c40a43510DfCB2aF9ea05305","gasPrice":{"type":"BigNumber","hex":"0x018148d4c3"},"gasLimit":{"type":"BigNumber","hex":"0x017a05"},"to":"0x2e95DE6abF74a45185c3541Ca1204c6f59B3ee13","value":{"type":"BigNumber","hex":"0x00"},"nonce":172,"data":"0xde9b9be0","r":"0x428a4c7918d5b8fa802759e6a84ce69ed733909483fd68ceb86324305eae763e","s":"0x2cca398ad98b5e2cca5f40c1d9e64f0b9de8dc057e0d0c57f11c4308abae5250","v":45,"creates":null,"chainId":5}, receipt={"to":"0x2e95DE6abF74a45185c3541Ca1204c6f59B3ee13","from":"0x88e6Bc4Fcb2665b2c40a43510DfCB2aF9ea05305","contractAddress":null,"transactionIndex":64,"gasUsed":{"type":"BigNumber","hex":"0x017a05"},"logsBloom":"0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000","blockHash":"0x87094617d41420943b5876d4877c07b7ebfeaefab00fdb78ac8fd043943dbd5b","transactionHash":"0x63dfd6f931550ebffd459049ce04b68e759a8d2dcedf62e2eaa671deb30c998b","logs":[],"blockNumber":7911764,"confirmations":1,"cumulativeGasUsed":{"type":"BigNumber","hex":"0x01873edc"},"effectiveGasPrice":{"type":"BigNumber","hex":"0x018148d4c3"},"status":0,"type":0,"byzantium":true}, code=CALL_EXCEPTION, version=providers/5.7.1)
    at Logger.makeError (/Users/jasnelson/Desktop/the-side-projects/js-nft/node_modules/@ethersproject/logger/src.ts/index.ts:269:28)
    at Logger.throwError (/Users/jasnelson/Desktop/the-side-projects/js-nft/node_modules/@ethersproject/logger/src.ts/index.ts:281:20)
    at EthersProviderWrapper.<anonymous> (/Users/jasnelson/Desktop/the-side-projects/js-nft/node_modules/@ethersproject/providers/src.ts/base-provider.ts:1549:24)
    at step (/Users/jasnelson/Desktop/the-side-projects/js-nft/node_modules/@ethersproject/providers/lib/base-provider.js:48:23)
    at Object.next (/Users/jasnelson/Desktop/the-side-projects/js-nft/node_modules/@ethersproject/providers/lib/base-provider.js:29:53)
    at fulfilled (/Users/jasnelson/Desktop/the-side-projects/js-nft/node_modules/@ethersproject/providers/lib/base-provider.js:20:58) {
  reason: 'transaction failed',
  code: 'CALL_EXCEPTION',
  transactionHash: '0x63dfd6f931550ebffd459049ce04b68e759a8d2dcedf62e2eaa671deb30c998b',
  transaction: {
    hash: '0x63dfd6f931550ebffd459049ce04b68e759a8d2dcedf62e2eaa671deb30c998b',
    type: 0,
    accessList: null,
    blockHash: null,
    blockNumber: null,
    transactionIndex: null,
    confirmations: 0,
    from: '0x88e6Bc4Fcb2665b2c40a43510DfCB2aF9ea05305',
    gasPrice: BigNumber { value: "6464001219" },
    gasLimit: BigNumber { value: "96773" },
    to: '0x2e95DE6abF74a45185c3541Ca1204c6f59B3ee13',
    value: BigNumber { value: "0" },
    nonce: 172,
    data: '0xde9b9be0',
    r: '0x428a4c7918d5b8fa802759e6a84ce69ed733909483fd68ceb86324305eae763e',
    s: '0x2cca398ad98b5e2cca5f40c1d9e64f0b9de8dc057e0d0c57f11c4308abae5250',
    v: 45,
    creates: null,
    chainId: 5,
    wait: [Function (anonymous)]
  },
  receipt: {
    to: '0x2e95DE6abF74a45185c3541Ca1204c6f59B3ee13',
    from: '0x88e6Bc4Fcb2665b2c40a43510DfCB2aF9ea05305',
    contractAddress: null,
    transactionIndex: 64,
    gasUsed: BigNumber { value: "96773" },
    logsBloom: '0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
    blockHash: '0x87094617d41420943b5876d4877c07b7ebfeaefab00fdb78ac8fd043943dbd5b',
    transactionHash: '0x63dfd6f931550ebffd459049ce04b68e759a8d2dcedf62e2eaa671deb30c998b',
    logs: [],
    blockNumber: 7911764,
    confirmations: 1,
    cumulativeGasUsed: BigNumber { value: "25640668" },
    effectiveGasPrice: BigNumber { value: "6464001219" },
    status: 0,
    type: 0,
    byzantium: true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the transaction **ran out of gas**. If you look up the hash of the transaction on etherscan, you'll see it.

[image]

https://goerli.etherscan.io/tx/0x63dfd6f931550ebffd459049ce04b68e759a8d2dcedf62e2eaa671deb30c998b

However, you can also see this in the response you received. The transaction's gas limit is `96773`, and it used up all of it.

**In transaction**: `gasLimit: BigNumber { value: "96773" },`

**In receipt**: `gasUsed: BigNumber { value: "96773" },`

You need to increase the `gasLimit` for the calls of `setNFTData()`, `makeJSNFT()`.

Comment: Thank you this worked for me, although i had to set it in the UI instead of the solidity code itself. But maybe it is better that way to have more control over it